# What the difference between != and =/= in chisel?

Tags: scala, hdl, chisel

The [Chisel cheat-sheet](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-cheatsheet) give two way do express inequality :

```
Chisel   Explanation   Width
==============================
x != y   Inequality    1
x =/= y  Inequality    1
```

Are `!=` and `=/=` equivalent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent, but `!=` is deprecated in favor of `=/=`.

I'll see about removing `!=` from the cheatsheet.